# scm type missing in "checkout as maven project from scm"

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, maven, version-control

I have installed

1. subclipse
2. maven integrator for eclipse

i went to

window -> preferences -> maven -> catalog ->

hoping to install

1. m2e connector for maven-scm-plugin
2. m2e-subclipse (Maven SCM handler for subclipse)
   but couldn't find them

until i install them i will not see the drop down list for scm type populated with the respective entries.

could someone please help me.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but i was using SVN. I used a workaround for this. I did `Checkout Projects from SVN` and afterwards did `Maven --> Enable Dependency Management` on the project. May be it will help.